# Is it true that , in a Euclidean space , union of two disjoint smooth manifolds of different dimensions can never be a manifold?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $A,B \subseteq \mathbb R^k$ be disjoint smooth manifolds of different dimensions , then is it rue that $A \cup B $ cannot be a smooth manifold ?

Comment: What is your definition of (topological or smooth) manifold. Actually, some authorsdo allow "mixed" dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

In ${\mathbb R}^2$ let
$$A:=\bigl\{(x,y)\,\bigm|\,1<x^2+y^2<4\bigr\}\setminus\bigl\{(x,0)\,\bigm|\,1<x<2\bigr\}\ ,\quad B:=\bigl\{(x,0)\,\bigm|\,1<x<2\bigr\}\ .$$

Comment: +1 Didn't think of that. Even if one requires that manifolds be pure and connected, $A=$open disk minus one point and $B=$that point would make a similar great example

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : can a single point be a smooth manifold ?

Comment: @SaunDev Okay, everything $\times \Bbb R$ if you prefer :)